# How to prevent event handlers in HTML attributes from firing?

Tags: javascript, html, dom

I recently learned that the browser will fire the `toggle` event of the `details` element simply by setting the contents on an element, even when it's not in the DOM. The following executes an alert:

```
document.createElement('p').innerHTML = "<details open ontoggle=\"alert('BAD')\">"
```

Same works for images and their `onload` event.

Compare this with using a `script` tag. The following does nothing:

```
document.createElement('p').innerHTML = "<script>alert('FINE')</script>"
```

Tested in Chrome and Firefox.

**Is there a way to suppress execution of inline event handlers like this? Ideally something that can be set on the parent element**

I considered adding an event handler on the parent, but the [toggle event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLDetailsElement/toggle_event) doesn't bubble!

An obvious solution is to sanitise the html source, but I am looking for something more graceful and bulletproof than string manipulation.

Comment: [Inline event handlers are garbage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Building_blocks/Events#inline_event_handlers_%E2%80%94_dont_use_these)

Comment: Yes, they are. And I'm not using them. Your link provides no answer to my question.

Comment: *"Is there a way to suppress execution of **inline event handlers** like this?"*  So if your'e not using them, but you are considering on using them -- hence the link explaining that you shouldn't consider using them. You agree that they are garbage by your reply, *"Yes, they are. "* So the link was helpful.

Comment: I am not using them. Other code that I don't control is using them. The context to precisely why I am asking is not relevant. They are parameters to my question. I did not ask "should I use inline event handlers?" or "what should I use instead?" I know how to do this properly, so your link was not useful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is [Content-Security-Policy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CSP). Simply don't allow `unsafe-inline`.

Comment: Excellent, thank you. Unfortunately my code is destined for a WordPress plugin so I do risk breaking other site functionality by forcing a meta tag. Might be ok as only on "my" admin screens. I'll investigate.